# Slack slash command picture processing

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Facing the issue where I need to use slash commands with new [SlackBolt](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#basic) framework

```
from slack_bolt import App

app = App()

@app.command("/detection")
def detection(ack, say, command, body):
    ack()
    
    print(command)
    print(body)
```

In slack channel/bot I'll use `/detection` and add the picture. How can I access the picture and do some processing in the background? Didn't find anything in the Bolt documentation. :(

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add more details? Are you uploading these image as an attachment ?

Comment: Hey, yes. I already have functioning endpoint to process the picture from URL but I'm looking for directly putting the image into the message (probably as an attachment - just dragged the image into the conversation) and having a slash command.

Comment: you should use 'Message Shortcut' instead of 'Slash Command'. It will help you put your image url in payload.